# Why is using empty array in useEffect not working - React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm using useEffect to fetch data through Axios and as I want that to fire only on the initial render I passed an empty array as a second argument ...

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
    const products = data
    setData(products)
    setLoading(false)
    setSortType('')
  }
  fetchData()
}, [])
```

And now I'm using another useEffect to sort the data that I fetched...

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (sortType == "price") {
    return setData([...data].sort((a, b) => a[sortType] - b[sortType]))
  }
  if (sortType == "title") {
    return setData([...data].sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.title.toLowerCase() < b.title.toLowerCase()) return -1
      if (a.title.toLowerCase() > b.title.toLowerCase()) return 1
      return 0
    }))
  }
}, [sortType])
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is whenever I try to sort the items, the second useEffect fires just followed by the first useEffect, which is causing the component to fetch the items all over again.
is there any other way I can run a function only on the initial render, or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: is it because you're calling `setSortType` in the first effect?

Comment: Why you need another useEffect if it can be done by using normal function, just use promise after yout get the data

Comment: I don't this is the cause of the issue, but your second `useEffect` hook callback is returning the result of `setData`, which I believe is a void return. You should only return effect cleanup functions from `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I have tried to mock the same code of yours into code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-fermi-x9gcp?file=/src/App.js)
I don't see any problem since the API call is happening only once and your dependencies also seem to be correct.
Please refer to the code sandbox code snippet I have attached and have a look at the console logs, let me know if you will be able to fix it.
(may be some problem with the way you are doing sorting)
Hope it helps.

Comment: @AnandGupta You're right, I've cleared it right after raising this issue. The problem was simple... I was using buttons inside a form to set sort type. As we know, buttons inside a form tag will have a default function of submitting. On clicking it was causing the entire page to rerender and firing the first useEffect all over. I forgot to add preventDefault() to the onClick function. Everything works fine after adding that. Thank you.